# DVI-D and VGA monitors with only one output port that is DVI-D

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I have an [LG Flatron W2253VP](http://www.lg.com/us/support-product/lg-W2253VP-PF) and an [HP vs17](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?cc=us&lc=en&product=447382) monitors that I want to connect to my bare-bones kit computer with only a DVI-D output. I am running Windows 7 Pro 64-bit with an AMD Phenom 9500 Quad-Core on an MSI motherboard.

I purchased a StarTech DVI-I to DVI-D adapter and DVI-I to DVI-D and VGA cable. Both monitors work as I have been upgrading a friends computer and using the LG on my computer and the HP on theirs. Windows is not detecting the second monitor. I’ve done everything I can think of to make Windows detect 2 monitors but no luck. I hope someone has the answer because I’m at my wits end here.

Comment: So your graphics output is a single DVI-D port and nothing else? If this is the case then you will only ever get one screen output. If you use a "Y" cable then you will only ever get duplicated output - not the ability to use the screens independently.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Which video ports are available on your PC? Which video ports are available on your monitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but that isn't going to work. Your DVI-D connector has only one "screen" worth of video in it, in just one format (digital). Converting it to DVI-I gives you a connector with both digital and analog formats, but it's still just one screen to the computer.

It would not even work if your computer had DVI-I output. A DVI-I connector has both digital (DVI) and VGA (analog) signals in it, but these almost invariably come from the same video source. Your DVI-I to DVI-D and VGA cable does not give you a second video source.

Return those cables if you can. Newegg is selling the nVidia EVGA 01G-P3-1312-LR GeForce 210 for just $35, and reviews show that it will run two monitors (one DVI, one VGA). You can probably get most of that just by returning the Startech cables.

What **would** work (but I don't recommend it) is a Matrox DualHead2Go adapter, one with DVI input and two VGA outputs. (Assuming both of your monitors can use VGA; I don't think they make one with one DVI and one VGA output.) But they are over $150. The Matrox adapters are good for situations where you simply can't change the video card.

Edit - added: I don't think a USB to VGA adapter is cost-effective. The USB to VGA adapters at Newegg are in the $37 to $75 range. Even at the high end of that price range the card will be **far** faster. The USB to VGA things are ok for business graphics, email, casual web browsing, stuff like that. otoh, the USB solution would be useful if you think you might want to use it with a laptop in the future.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was afraid of but it's good to have confirmation. Guess that just means i'm going to have to try to save faster. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend purchasing a USB VGA display adapter. They're fairly cheap and can be picked up at any local shop. That will allow you to connect your second monitor in extended mode.